# How to add a image with center alignment in CListCtrl using LVITEM

Tags: image, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I am trying to set center alignment for second column in CListCtrl which has image in its contents. How to do that?

```
    m_MyListCtrl.InsertColumn(0, L"No.", LVCFMT_LEFT, 75);
    m_MyListCtrl.InsertColumn(1, L"Result", LVCFMT_LEFT, 75); // this column has image which needs to be center aligned
    m_MyListCtrl.InsertColumn(2, L"values", LVCFMT_LEFT, 75);
    m_MyListCtrl.InsertColumn(3, L"description", LVCFMT_LEFT, 75);


    //Adding a image from the image list like below
    lvi.iItem = nListItem;
    lvi.iSubItem = nSubItem;
    lvi.iImage = 2;//(takes image from the image list loaded)
```

Comment: If you need content to be centered, why are you passing `LVCFMT_LEFT`?

Comment: I changed that to LVCFMT_CENTER but only the column header changes not the content(image)

Comment: like we have alignment (fmt, 2nd column) in LVCOLUMN, do we have any such value in LVITEM

Comment: You might need to do a owner-drawn list control if you want to perform rendering that is outside the scope of the default control behaviour.